# Compiling .java file using javac gives "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, cmd

I'm absolute novice to the world of Java but i'll explain as best I can. 
I have a .jar file, in which in the \be\foundation\xroute directory I have a file called TollCalculation.class
This file needs some small changes so I decompiled the file using jd-gui and saved the results as .java
Made the changes I need and now i'm trying to re-compile it to a .class file using a cmd prompt and "javac TollCalculation.java"

This however gives me a number of error messages of the type "error: cannot find symbol".

I'm completely lost to what can cause this as the original .class file seems to be working correctly.

Error messages: 
[image: Error message]

Can someone guide me in the right direction to how to compile this .java file successfully?

edit:

used -classpath jarfile.jar while using javac, this resulted in 16 errors. Messages:

[image]

Comment: Your `TollCalculation` class depends on the other classes to be compiled successfully. Since you didn't compile its dependencies, you can't successfully compile the class itself. Take a look on [how to compile multiple source files](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/tools/using-javac-command#CompileMultiple).

Comment: There indeed was another .class file in the same directory. I've converted both to .java, made changes, and tried to compile both files in the same action as you've mentioned, however still it shows about 68 errors, all pointing to the original TollCalculation.java file. 

Next I tried to reference to the original .jar file via - classpath and it shows 16 errors.

Comment: So, from 68 errors you passed to 16 errors?

Comment: correct; by adding the -classpath *jarfile*.jar, I went to 16 errors. No clue how to solve these though. Went through the page as supplied by aribeiro but couldnt find anything else.

Comment: And the error's you're seeing now, do they refer to your classes? Do you mind updating your question with the new errors?

Comment: Done, see OP for new image

Comment: How's the class `RoutingOptions` being provided? Where is it defined? You need to do the same as you did before with the previous dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've tried -classpath do another .jar file with more definitions but still 16 errors. In the meantime i've passed on this issue to an external professional, he might be able to tackle this.